# Unable to start embedded Tomcat NoClassDefFoundError DispatcherServletPath

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

My **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.qroom</groupId>
<artifactId>qroom</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>qroom</name>
<description>qRoom Server</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

When I'm starting my app, I'm getting following error:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at com.qroom.QroomApplication.main(QroomApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       ... 8 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletPath
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletPath
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 23 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletPath
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:71) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6542fda.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0() ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6542fda$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dc5ad488.invoke() ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6542fda.servletEndpointRegistrar() ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 24 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>       ... 35 common frames omitted

**nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletPath**
 I found, that the problem is in **spring-cloud-starter-oauth2** dependency. Everything works fine if I remove it. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions (2.0.4 and 2.0.2) of the same framework. To override the hibernate version add `<hibernate.version>5.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>` to the `<properties>` element and remove the `hibernate` dependency. **NOTE:** `DispatcherServletPath` was added in Spring Boot 2.0.4 so probably your version mismatch is the root cause of this issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum? thank you very much, it helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M. Deinum's comment helped me to solve the problem

> For starters stop mixing versions (2.0.4 and 2.0.2) of the same framework. To override the hibernate version add 5.3.5.Final to the  element and remove the hibernate dependency. NOTE: DispatcherServletPath was added in Spring Boot 2.0.4 so probably your version mismatch is the root cause of this issue

Answer (score 0):

Maven can not resolve your dependency without version if you don't use `dependencyManagement`. Add version tag for `org.springframework.cloud`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That isn't true. When using a `dependencyManagement` section in your `pom.xml` you can declare the dependencies you want. Spring Boot provides that in its parent and thus you can leave out the version. The same applies to the, so called, BOM (Bill of Materials) dependencies which supply consistent versioning.

Comment: I didn't saw dependencyManagement, thanks for correction.